# Poedit diesnt translate few words

Tags: html, wordpress, translate, poedit

So poedit doesn't translate few words, where is symbol - & and these long sentences. Is there any fix for that?

```
  msgid "Get Email Tips & Tricks"
  msgstr "Получать советы & рекомендации по email маркетингу"
```

and other interesting feature is that it make something like this

```
msgid ""
"Take a test drive of xxxx and send your first email campaign in just "
"minutes! It's FREE. No commitment and no payment information required"
msgstr ""
"Зрегистрируйтесь в xxxx и отправте email кампанию всего за несколько "
"минут!  Это бесплатно. Оплата и договоров не требуется"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the & symbol try encoding it as

```
&amp;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that "Poedit doesn't translate" this — you show an excerpt of the file saved by Poedit that clearly shows everything in place.

Your problem is on the other end: with whatever part of WordPress it is (you don't say) that you are using on the server to *display* the translations. It seems it has quite a few bugs in it: for one thing, it doesn't properly escape "&" when outputting HTML markup, which it really should; probably because a wrong gettext function from the WP arsenal is used (e.g. not using the `esc_*` family of functions).

Whatever problem you're seeing with the long texts (it's not clear from the question), it is probably something similarly silly. I'm afraid you'll have to debug it the old fashioned way — go look at the code that outputs the long msgid to see what it does.